# How to correctly mount configMap with subPath in Kubernetes? Not update configs after changes

Tags: kubernetes

I tried to use configMap to mount some configs in a subdirectory. For example:

```
spec.template.spec.containers.[0].volumeMounts:
  - name: fh16-volume
    mountPath: /etc/fh-16/application.log
    subPath: my-config.txt
spec.template.spec.volumes:
  - name: fh16-volume
    configMap:
      name: my-config
```

At this scenario, all mount as expected. But after any changes in configMap, this changes not applied in a container. Need to recreate pod for this.

It looks like some bug, but maybe I make some mistake in my configurations? In the case when I don't use subPath directive, all works as expected.

Answer (score 4):

See this note in the [Kubernetes docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#configmap):

> Note: A container using a ConfigMap as a subPath volume mount will not receive ConfigMap updates."

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like some bug

Yes, it is: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/50345

Answer (score 0):

This is currently expected behavior. kubelet update the content inside container on a timer.

See https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/30189